# Grunt html validator : Avoid Jenkins mark build as failure on connection timeout / reset

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs, npm, w3c

I am using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-html-validation

Here is my validation task in Grunt:

```
validation: {
        partial: {
            options: {
                reset: grunt.option('reset') || true,
                stoponerror: false,
                failHard: true,
                maxTry: 1,
                doctype: 'HTML5',
                relaxerror: []
            },
            files: {
                src: [
                    'apps/www/partials/*.html',
                    'apps/www/partials/**/*.html'
                ]
            }
        },
```

After a lot of build the connection is refused by the W3C which is fine but I do not want to fail the build in Jenkins for this reason:

> Error: 32mValidation started for..
>   [39mapps/www/partials/asset-library.html [31mFatal error: read
>   ECONNRESET[39m

Comment: Your build step should not produce a non-0 exit code, if you don't want build marked as failure.

Comment: I do want to produce a failure if there are validation errors, not for any time out for w3c of connection errors

Comment: So the build should appear successful, even if it isn't? How often does this connection timeout? Why not set the `maxTry` value to something much higher than `1`?

Comment: @ChristopherOrr occurs about once a month, because too many queries to w3c blocks me. The maxTry will not change anything once I am blocked it fails the first time. Yes correct I want the build to fail only if a validation fails for an HTML error not because w3c API is unreachable once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **[Text-finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)**. Have your tests produce 0 exit code (so the build doesn't fail outright). Then configure a regex in Text-finder plugin, to search through your console log (or other workspace files).

Configure the regex in such a way that it searches for all test failure results (other than connection timeout). If found, mark the build `FAILED` (or `UNSTABLE` would be preferred to differentiate build failure vs test failure)

Comment: Hi Slav, yes I know how to do this but one issue, how do you force an exit 0 from a plugin?

Comment: How are you calling the validation task?

Comment: via Grunt, you can see the definition of it in my question, the name is 'validation'. The all thing is called via the shell in Jenkins

Comment: If you call *just* the validation from shell, you can write immediately after the Grunt command line something like `echo tests done`. This way, the last command of the "execute shell" build step will always be 0, therefore success (and you will manually fail it with Text-finder based on your regex